# Switch statement in PHP injected HTML

Tags: php, templates, switch-statement

```
<? switch ($var): ?>
  <? case 1: ?>
    It's 1!
  <? break ?>
<? endswitch ?>
```

I want to do something like that, in other words use the switch statement in PHP templates. This is possible with the if statement. The above code generates `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_INLINE_HTML, expecting T_ENDSWITCH or T_CASE or T_DEFAULT` in PHP 5.3. The [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) suggests that this should be possible.

Can someone confirm that this doesn't work, or rather, tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You should use `<?php` instead of just `<?` - the short version has been deprecated.

Comment: Where do you see this in the documentation?  I went to the link you provided, but I can't find anything about supporting mixing inline HTML with a switch statement.

Comment: <? (short tags) have not been deprecated, they are just avoided because of incompatibility with some server configurations.

Comment: As @Steve says, they are not deprecated. And a lot nicer to use. @AJ I was referring to the section on switch():, but no it doesn't say anything about mixing.

Comment: Tell that to your IDE, your sys admin and newbies on SO. The more a language is clear, the more it is used. English is a nice illustration : simple and efficient, brought to international language in a minute.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I read in the php doc that your example should not work.

> Any output (including whitespace) between a switch statement and the
>   first case will result in a syntax error. For example, this is invalid

Try this instead:

```
<div>
<?php switch($variable): 
case 1: ?>
    <div>
    Newspage
    </div>
<?php break; ?>
<?php case 2: ?>
    </div>
    Forum
    <div>
<?php break; ?>
<?php endswitch; ?>
</div>
```

http://php.net/control-structures.alternative-syntax

Comment: Thanks! (for everyone else, the code is from [this comment](http://se2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php#80668))

Answer (score 16):

You have

```
?>\n\n<?
```

after your switch which becomes

```
switch($var):
echo "\n\t";
case 1:
```

Think of your script as PHP with HTML in it, rather than embellished HTML. The PHP binary gets the file first.

You might like to use something like HEREDOC to echo out unescaped HTML.

Answer (score 9):

I use this "friendly formatting". Tested and working:

```
<? switch($var) : case 1 : ?>

  <p>One</p>

<? break; case 2 : ?>

  <p>Two</p>

<? break; case 3 : ?>

  <p>Three</p>

<? break; default : ?>

  <p>Default Value</p>

<? endswitch; ?>
```

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly for my question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64427621/why-is-my-div-firstpage-displaying-on-my-div-lastpage-when-the-div-firstpage

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar issue when using a switch or a foreach statement with the new style short tags running on php 5.6.

in my case: changing

```
<?=

  switch ($number_of_columns) {
    case "1":
        echo '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12" >';
        break;
    case "2":
        echo '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6" >';
        break;
    case "4":
        echo '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" >';
        break;
    default:
        echo '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" >';
    }
?>
```

to

```
 <?php 
      switch ($number_of_columns) {
        case "1":
            echo '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12" >';
            break;
        case "2":
            echo '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6" >';
            break;
        case "4":
            echo '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" >';
            break;
        default:
            echo '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" >';
        }
    ?>
```

resulted in no syntax error i.e. syntax error, unexpected 'switch' (T_SWITCH)