# Alternative syntax for switch

Tags: php

Hey there is an alternative syntax for switch statement in PHP, but this code doesn't work:

```
<div>
<?php switch($variable): ?>
<?php case 1: ?>
<div>
Newspage
</div>
<?php break;?>
<?php case 2: ?>
</div>
Forum
<div>
<?php break;?>
<?php endswitch;?>
</div>
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_INLINE_HTML, expecting
>   T_ENDSWITCH or T_CASE or T_DEFAULT in /path/to/file on line #

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Solution for this problem is putting `switch($variable):` with `case 1:` into same block of PHP code:

```
<div>
<?php switch($variable): 
case 1: ?>
<div>
Newspage
</div>
<?php break;?>
<?php case 2: ?>
</div>
Forum
<div>
<?php break;?>
<?php endswitch;?>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the same example from the comments in the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php#80668), but is there an explainable reason for why this works, but the code in the question doesn't? Or is it just a bug in PHP?

Comment: Nevermind. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6096600/259457) provides some explanation. You're basically inserting a line break, which aren't allowed directly within a `switch` statement (outside of `case`s. In an `if` statement or a loop, it's not a problem to have a line break, but `switch` is different.